# Nginx ingress not routing to backend services

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy Prometheus and Grafana using helm on my Kubernetes cluster .After deployment i am setting up ingress rule for the two svc but its not working.
Any suggestions
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: demo-grafana
namespace: monitoring
annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
ingressClassName: nginx
rules:

- http:
  paths:

  - path:  /grafana
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: prometheus-grafana
    port:
    number: 80
  - path:  /prometheus
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
    port:
    number: 9090

kubectl describe ingress demo-grafana -n monitoring
Name:             demo-grafana
Labels:           
Namespace:        monitoring
Address:          20.219.78.89
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  
Rules:
Host        Path  Backends

---

- ```
        /grafana      prometheus-grafana:80 (10.244.0.15:3000)
        /prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus:9090 (10.244.0.9:9090)
  ```

Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
Events:
Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message

---

Normal  Sync    17s (x2 over 20s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync